# How to send data to Socket server via PHP

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I would like to develop an application, which get data from `cronjob` (using `PHP`) and send to client's browsers.

I created a socket server successfully, and got connections from browsers.
[image]

Next step, I create a file to connect to this socket server. Below is content

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$connection =  @socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', 8080);

if( $connection ){
    echo 'ONLINE';
}
else {
    echo 'OFFLINE: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error( $socket ));
}

$a = socket_write($socket, 'AAAA');
var_dump($a);
```

As the result, `ONLINE` and `4` appeared, but no any connections were detected in command line. (I checked IP and port many times, its correct).
I don't know what are missing or wrong? 
Sorry for my bad English

**UPDATE SOCKER SERVER SCRIPT**

```
require '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connections' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv);

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
$server->run();
```

Comment: What is your server side code?

Comment: I updated my post